# Trouble passing RSpec test. Time can't be coerced into Fixnum

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm having trouble with this rspec test.  I'm using Ruby 1.93 and RSPEC 2.14.8 (I think) Sorry for how long this post will be.  I can get the other code that I found to work but I cannot get my code to work and I'm not sure why.

My code:

```
def measure(number = 1)  
  counter = number  
  total = 0  
  while counter > 0  
  start = Time.now  
  counter-=1  

yield

 stop = Time.now
 total = total + stop - start

end

 total / number
end
```

Other code that I found that works:

```
def measure count=1  
     total_time = 0  
     count.times do  
     start_time = Time.now  

yield  

    end_time = Time.now  
    total_time += end_time - start_time  
end  
    total_time / count  
end
```

The test:

```
require_relative "performance_monitor"  

require "time"  # loads up the Time.parse method -- do NOT create time.rb!  

describe "Performance Monitor" do  
  before do  
    @eleven_am = Time.parse("2011-1-2 11:00:00")  
  end  

  it "takes about 0 seconds to run an empty block" do  
    elapsed_time = measure do  
    end  
    elapsed_time.should be_within(0.1).of(0)  
  end  

  it "takes exactly 0 seconds to run an empty block (with stubs)" do  
    Time.stub(:now) { @eleven_am }  
    elapsed_time = measure do  
    end  
    elapsed_time.should == 0  
  end  

  it "takes about 1 second to run a block that sleeps for 1 second" do  
    elapsed_time = measure do  
      sleep 1  
    end  
    elapsed_time.should be_within(0.1).of(1)  
  end  

  it "takes exactly 1 second to run a block that sleeps for 1 second (with stubs)" do  
    fake_time = @eleven_am   
    Time.stub(:now) { fake_time }  
    elapsed_time = measure do  
      fake_time += 60  # adds one minute to fake_time  
    end  
    elapsed_time.should == 60  
  end  

  it "runs a block N times" do  
    n = 0  
     measure(4) do  
         n += 1  
    end  
    n.should == 4  
   end  

  it "returns the average time, not the total time, when running multiple times" do  
    run_times = [8,6,5,7]  
     fake_time = @eleven_am  
    Time.stub(:now) { fake_time }  
    average_time = measure(4) do  
      fake_time += run_times.pop  
    end  
    average_time.should == 6.5  
  end  

  it "returns the average time when running a random number of times for random lengths of time" do   
    fake_time = @eleven_am  
    Time.stub(:now) { fake_time }  
    number_of_times = rand(10) + 2  
    average_time = measure(number_of_times) do  
      delay = rand(10)  
      fake_time += delay  
    end  
    average_time.should == (fake_time - @eleven_am).to_f/number_of_times  
  end  

end
```

What it says when I run it:

> Performance Monitor   takes about 0 seconds to run an empty block
>   (FAILED - 1)
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) Performance Monitor takes about 0 seconds to run an empty block
>        Failure/Error: elapsed_time = measure do
>        TypeError:
>          Time can't be coerced into Fixnum
>        # ./06_performance_monitor/performance_monitor.rb:11:in '+'  #./06_performance_monitor/performance_monitor.rb:11:in 'measure'
>          #./06_performance_monitor/performance_monitor_spec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 0.008 seconds   1 example, 1 failure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`total = total + stop - start` is not the same as `total = total + (stop - start)`

The first is actually evaluating as `total = (total + t) - n` which doesn't work since you can't add two times together.

I think what you mean to do is:

`total = total + (stop - start)` or a more concise `total += stop - start`

Comment: Thank you.  I would up vote your answer but my reputation is to low.

Comment: Isn't `total = total + (stop - start)` still adding two times together after the first loop?

Comment: `stop - start` will return a Float (the number of seconds between the two times) not a Time. You can add a Float to a Time. Try playing around with this in irb to get a feel for what's going on. It usually helps me figure out how Ruby works.

Comment: Thank you again.  I will rewrite it in irb and play with it some.